# ping multiple server and save in CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm new in PowerShell scripting and need a help.

I have a txt file with server IPadd, the below script calls the txt file and show the server status UP/Down in CSVformat. What I need is to get the CSV file result role base, if I add the line Domain Controller in txt and mention the IP address, I get the result Domain Controller--Down and IPAdd with proper status. Also I can either mention IPadd or hostname. Need your help to get the CSV report with Hostname, IP address and Status with title (Role)

**Script:**

```
$Servers = Get-Content D:\test\ServerStatus.txt
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)

{
    $status = @{ "ServerName" = $server}
    if (Test-Connection -Computername $Server -Count 2 -ea 0 -Quiet)

    {
        $status["Results"] = "Up"
    }
    else
    {
        $status["Results"] = "Down"
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
    $collection += $serverStatus

}
$collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath d:\ServerStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to initalize `$collection` as an array using:

```
$collection = @()
```

instead of:

```
$collection = $()
```